# (Flutter) Is it possible to make bottomSheet of Scaffold transparent?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, scaffold

I've recently developed comment view below the detail posts.

Like the image I attached, **I'd like to show images for each comment but the image Container should be transparent to see the last comment.**

But I think Scaffold doesn't allow bottomSheet to have transparent children.

Are there anyone having an idea to solve this problem?

[image]

```
class PostDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final int maxRenderImgCnt = 4;
  final Post post;

  PostDetail(this.post);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar( ... ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView( ... ),
      bottomSheet: CommonTextField(onTap: null, editTarget: null),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the widget with an opacity widget but there is also another way which is more efficient even for changing it later, that is the ThemeData widget:

```
bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
),
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me :) But bottomSheetTheme Widget seems not applicable as a **bottomSheet** child under **Scaffold** Widget because there is no child option 'bottomSheetTheme' in Scaffold

Comment: You use this inside ThemeData not the Scaffold. You need to have a Theme for your application so that you don't have to manually add colors or fonts for texts or other widgtes. and there is so many ways for doing that you can search for it.